# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

The query is meant to return the percentage based on value from one table being divided by the value of another table. However, there is something wrong and I am missing it.

similar problems noted on the board looked related to JOIN, but did not seem to be the problem, when I tried and explicit join -- basically mysql was like -- now you are an idiot-- I must have did that wrong or that is not the problem.

```
    SELECT (pathogenPop / locationpop) as PercentInfected
       FROM ( 
       (SELECT apinfectcount.APInfectCountInfected 
       as pathogenPop, apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation
       FROM apstart.apinfectcount 
       GROUP BY apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation) as pathogenPop

           Inner JOIN 

       (SELECT apcountrypop.apcountrypopPopulation 
       as locationpop, apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry
       FROM apstart.apcountrypop 
       GROUP BY apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry) 
       as locationpop
       on apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation = apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry 
       and apinfectcount.APInfectCountWeek = 23);
```

**Table Schema:** apcountrypop

```
    idapcountrypop          INT(11)
    apcountrypopCountry     VarChar(45)
    apcountrypopPopulation  FLOAT
```

**Table Schema:** apinfectcount

```
    idAPInfectCount         INT(11)
    APInfectCountLocation   VarChar(45)
    APInfectCountOutBreak   VarChar(45)
    APInfectCountPathogen   VarChar(45)
    APInfectCountInfected   FLOAT
    APInfectCountDead       FLOAT
    APInfectCountWeek       VarChar(45)
```

If it worked -- 
it would assign apinfectcount.APInfectCountInfected to pathogenPop
and apcountrypop.apcountrypopPopulation to locationpop

for the values where the locations are the same(apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation = apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry)

then it would return the value of the apinfectcount table value is divided by the apcountrypop table to give the percentage.

so in this specific example I only have sample data so I am just wanted to return one value so I added the where clause to just test the logic and syntax.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: make MySQL report more about the error and you will know what column name or a missing name causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  This issue is fixed, but still not working... going to do some more research to fix it.  I'll post the updated code when its done.   I really genuinely appreciate the help!

Comment: HI all-- all the responses worked below.  I found the issue why it was returning no results .... total rookie move.    There was a spelling error in the DB.  LOL.  I could not have fixed without you.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have assugned the tables alias pathogenPop and  locationpop so 
you need   `pathogenPop.APInfectCountLocation = locationpop.apcountrypopCountry 
         and pathogenPop.APInfectCountWeek = 23`  in ON clause

```
SELECT (pathogenPop / locationpop) as PercentInfected
     FROM ( 
     (SELECT apinfectcount.APInfectCountInfected 
     as pathogenPop, apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation
     FROM apstart.apinfectcount 
     GROUP BY apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation) as pathogenPop

         Inner JOIN 

     (SELECT apcountrypop.apcountrypopPopulation 
     as locationpop, apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry
     FROM apstart.apcountrypop 
     GROUP BY apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry) 
     as locationpop
     on pathogenPop.APInfectCountLocation = locationpop.apcountrypopCountry 
     and pathogenPop.APInfectCountWeek = 23) T;
```

and also a table alias  for the outer  FROM(..) T

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the database to test against so I'm not 100% certain this will run, but would the following query not be a bit simpler?

```
SELECT (apinfectcount.APInfectCountInfected / apcountrypop.apcountrypopPopulation) as PercentInfected, apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation
FROM apinfectcount
INNER JOIN apcountrypop  ON apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry = apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation
WHERE  apinfectcount.APInfectCountWeek = 23
GROUP BY apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation
```

And I assume there is only one location record per location in each table?

Comment: let me try this out.  thanks so much for the reply! actually-- in the apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation has many records with the same location.  Do I need to assign it as a foreign key?

Comment: sorry I can't figure out how to format the comments yet-- but this was a great suggestion.   I made a few edits and it worked.  Still not getting results so I have to spend more time working on it, but your suggestion worked.

Comment: SELECT (apinfectcount.APInfectCountInfected / apcountrypop.apcountrypopPopulation) as PercentInfected, apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation
FROM apstart.apinfectcount
INNER JOIN apstart.apcountrypop  ON apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry = apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation
WHERE  apinfectcount.APInfectCountWeek = 23
GROUP BY apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation;

Comment: If there are multiple records for a single location, you want to SUM() the field you're selecting and GROUP BY. Comments are not great for formatting code

Comment: SELECT (SUM(apinfectcount.APInfectCountInfected) / SUM(apcountrypop.apcountrypopPopulation)) as PercentInfected, apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation
FROM apinfectcount
INNER JOIN apcountrypop  ON apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry = apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation
WHERE  apinfectcount.APInfectCountWeek = 23
GROUP BY apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation, apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue within a query. As scope of apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation column and apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry column is limited to subquery only you cannot use it outside the subquery (within where clause).
You can check out these docs on subquery https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017

Refer code below.

```
SELECT (countInfected / countrypopulation) as PercentInfected
   FROM ( 
   (SELECT apinfectcount.APInfectCountInfected 
   as countinfected, apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation, APInfectCountWeek as 
   countweek
   FROM apstart.apinfectcount 
   GROUP BY apinfectcount.APInfectCountLocation) as pathogenPop

       Inner JOIN 

   (SELECT apcountrypop.apcountrypopPopulation 
   as countrypopulation, apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry
   FROM apstart.apcountrypop 
   GROUP BY apcountrypop.apcountrypopCountry) 
   as locationpop
   on pathogenPop.countinfected = locationpop.countrypopulation
   and pathogenPop.countweek= 23);
```

Comment: this solved this issue: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column in 'on clause'

Comment: Returning no results so I still have a little work to do.   But at least I can move forward past the syntax issue :)

Comment: Hi Ravina!  question if you have a min--what is this meant to do-- I'm not understanding the line,  good news is it runs.  <br/>    on pathogenPop.countinfected = locationpop.countrypopulation, but not getting results.